# Android app crashing on method call from menu item

Tags: java, android, dynamic, listener, android-gridlayout

I have a function called `createGrid` that crates a grid of buttons in a `Gridlayout` (code below), sets their listener and adds a custom layout called no_padding_button to each one.

after creating the grid, depending on what button(s) the user has clicked on I have another function called `saveDesign` that iterates through the `gridlayout` and returns the number of clicked buttons depending on their tag. I call `saveDesign` from a menu Item.

The problem is that as soon as I called the `saveDesign` method, the app crashes.
The grid works fine, you click buttons, they change color and their tag changes but some reason trying to read through the `gridlayout` crashes the app.

can you guys help me understand what the error in my code is?

Thanks

```
//method to create a new grid, the number of rows and columns come from the dialogue inside the activity and then passed to this function
void createGrid(final Context context, GridLayout gridLayout) {

    gridLayout.setColumnCount(totalColumns);    //set the number of rows of the gridlayout
    gridLayout.setRowCount(totalRows);          //set the number of columns of the grid layout

    //add the buttons and implement their listeners
    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++) {
            Button button = new Button(context);
            //no padding
            button.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_padding_button));
            //set the name of the button according to its position
            button.setText(Integer.toString(i) + "," + Integer.toString(j)+",");
            //hide the name, the user does not need to see this information at this moment
            button.setTextColor(View.INVISIBLE);

            //setting up the layout parameters for each button
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            button.setLayoutParams(param);

            //button listener
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                boolean already_clicked = false;
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //on click, hide the button
                    Button button = (Button) v;
                    if(!already_clicked){
                    //change the color of the selected buttons as an indication
                    button.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_button));
                        button.setTag(1);
                        already_clicked =true;
                    }
                    else{
                        button.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.unselected_button));
                        button.setTag(0);
                        already_clicked =false;
                    }
                }
            });

            gridLayout.addView(button);
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(context, "Grid Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

saveDesing method:

```
public void saveDesign(){
    int temp=0;
    for (int i=0;i<gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
        Button childButton = (Button)gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if(childButton.getTag().toString() == "1"){
            temp++;
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(temp), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

the xml code of the activity holding the gridlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

        </GridLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

**UPDATE 1** the error log , i also tried string.equals("1") but i got the same error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.test.gridtest, PID: 3247
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.abtin.gridtest.MainActivity.saveDesign(MainActivity.java:85)
                      at com.example.abtin.gridtest.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:109)
                      at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3204)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:406)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                      at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:667)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:947)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:616)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:153)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: What does it say in your logcat?

Comment: Also: [How do I compare strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/3788176).

Comment: Post your logcat, it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't click on button, it haven't tag. Therefore childButton.getTag() return null and toString crash your app.
So check in saveDesign()

```
if(childButton.getTag() != null) {
    if(childButton.getTag().toString() == "1"){
        temp++;
    }
}
```

or set button tag when create button.

Comment: you sir are a goddamn genius, thank you so much man. that was it :D